# Customize Windows 10 UWP back button

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

Is there any way to customize the background color and Size of the UWP App_Back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to customize title bar. I think this article would be helpful for you:
[Easily manage the Title Bar in Windows 10 apps](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/)

For example, you can edit color with [ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.titlebar.aspx):

```
var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Maroon;
titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Yellow;
```

Or you can even find by this link solution how to remove chrome and create your own chrome with back button (a little bit complicated way)

The idea is to set application "chromeless" with [CoreApplication class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.titlebar.aspx) and code like:

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

After this you can create your XAML element to be instead of Title Bar with help of [Window.SetTitleBar method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar.aspx)

Comment: I agree with your solution. Plus I did not know about about the possibility of a custom chrome, thanks!